# mediawiki and wordpress MU different root with Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, wordpress, mediawiki, wordpress-mu

i want to use wordpress MU with mediawiki on the same domain , but i'm using a kind of mediawiki hosting service called [wikifamily](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family).

so i have to different script root :

1. /var/www/wikifamly for mediawiki
2. /var/www/blogs for wordpress

I want to use it like this :

1. mydomain.com or mydomain.com/blog for blog
2. mydomain.com/wiki for mediawiki

I tried to write some think like :

```
map $http_host $blogid {
    default -999;
}

server {
    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/blogs/;
    index index.php;

    location /wiki {

            index index.php index.html index.html;
            root /var/www/wikifamly;
            rewrite ^/?wiki/(.*)$ /index.php?title=$1 last;
            rewrite ^/?wiki/*$ /index.php last;
            rewrite ^/*$ /index.php last;

            location ~* \.php {
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_sc$
            }
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    #WPMU Files
    location ~ ^/files/(.*)$ {
            try_files /wp-content/blogs.dir/$blogid/$uri /wp-includes/ms-fi$
            access_log off; log_not_found off;      expires max;
    }

    #WPMU x-sendfile to avoid php readfile()
     location ^~ /blogs.dir {
            internal;
            alias /var/www/blogs/htdocs/wp-content/blogs.dir;
            access_log off; log_not_found off;      expires max;
    }
}
```

it's work great with wordpress but no sense with mediawiki

any help please and thanks in advance .

Comment: What subdomain will you use for the wiki? You did not say.

Comment: there is no subdomains as i say mydomain.com/wiki for the mediawiki

Comment: You can't do that if you're going to do a wiki family.

Comment: i have multi domain i can't use subdomain for each wiki

Comment: Then you aren't making a wiki family.

Comment: can you explain why i cant please  :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7646/discussion-between-eyadof-and-michael-hampton)